# How to optimize website for SEO when content is accessed via one search field

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing

We are developing a website (sort of information index for companies) where almost all content is accessed via one search field (similar to Google): you type a search phrase, get results and then can click on the link that leads to actual information page of the company. These are the most important pages to be indexed. In company page, there are keywords (tags) that you can click on and get resuts for that keyword.

Obviously, search engines won't enter all possible search variants to that search field to get links to the companies and I guess that keyword linking in the company info page is not enough.

I think that submitting sitemaps to search engines should help a lot. But are there any other solutions to get content indexed on the website of this sort?

Comment: How many pages do you have?

Comment: About 90K at the moment but the number keeps growing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question;

If you shared the website URL than it can more helpful for me to provide best suitable solution.

By considering your requirement what is suggest is:

- Create static page by company type or alphabetic sequence or industry category. This page will contain list of companies comes under specific category.
- Enlist those category page on your home page (home page is the best place from where most of the pages are being crawled by search engine).

You can also create top 10 company section on your home page based on search query (this will enlist those 10 companies based on search trends)

Still if you are not convinced with this solution; kindly share link of your website for study and will suggest best possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I like these suggestions. Website is still in development so I can't tell the URL but I will consider this solution. Thanks again =)

Comment: thats great...you can msg me anytime if you stuck anywhere